# VScodeでユーザーフォルダ階層の下の情報が全てリンクされてしまいました。

Tags: vscode

VScodeを使用していて、間違えてユーザーフォルダ階層の下の情報が全てリンクされてしまい、表示を無くしたかったのですが、削除以外の方法が思いつきませんでした。
（削除はまだしていません）

VScode上のユーザーフォルダ階層の下の情報リンクを解除したいのですが、
『vscode user階層 リンク 解除できない』
で検索しても、解決法を得られませんでした。

解除方法は無いものなのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: VSCodeの使用者には分かるのでしょうが、これはどんな状態なのかスクリーンショットとその何処が問題なのか画像で説明があった方が良いかもしれません。もしかしたらこんなもの？[【簡単・画像で詳しく解説】VSCodeで現在のファイルの階層が一瞬でわかるようにする方法。（ファイルパスの表示設定）](https://prograshi.com/general/editor/vscode-breadcrumbs/) あるいはこんなものとか？ [\[VScode\] フォルダ表示がシンプル化されて使いづらい時の対処方法](https://wordpress.ideacompo.com/?p=15463)

Comment: 「リンクされる」とはどのような状態のことを指していますか？

Comment: 仮に,ワークスペースに 間違ってフォルダーが追加されたということなら, 該当するフォルダーで右クリックからの「ワークスペースからフォルダーを削除」で。それ以外の話ならやはり「リンク」が何を示しているか説明がないと分かりません

Comment: ”リンク”がわかりづらくてすみません！

Comment: 質問内容に画像を添付しました。VScodeにユーザーフォルダの下の階層にある、個人的な情報まで反映されている、といったニュアンスになります。これを、初めてVScodeを開いた時の何も反映されていない状態に戻したいです。

Comment: ユーザーの homeフォルダーが追加された状態ならば, 該当するフォルダーで右クリックからの「ワークスペースからフォルダーを削除」で。ユーザーの homeフォルダーは含まれていて構わないとするなら, その下位層も表示されます (閉じてるか開いてるかは別として)

Comment: ワークスペースも何も無い状態なら, どこか適当なフォルダーで「フォルダーを開く」を試すとよいかも

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ユーザーの homeフォルダーを開いてる状態なのか
まっさらの状態で, ユーザーの homeフォルダーが追加された状態なのか
どちらの状態なのか不明なため, 後者と考えて手順記します

まっさらの状態で, ユーザーの homeフォルダーが追加された状態であれば, 該当するフォルダーで右クリックからの「ワークスペースからフォルダーを削除」で, (追加したフォルダーを)削除できます
(ワークスペース指定していない状態だと, もしかすると別のメッセージかも？)

Comment: 後者の内容で作業したら解決しました！ありがとうございました！